# need to convert data one format to another from mongodb query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

need to convert data one format to another from mongodb query

I need to convert below data

```
{
    "data" : [ 
        {
            "2020-11-19T05:00:00" : 20.98003
        }, 
        {
            "2020-11-18T05:00:00" : 20.98003
        }
    ]
}
```

to the below format from mongo query

```
{
    "data" : {
    
            "2020-11-19T05:00:00" : 20.98003,
      
            "2020-11-18T05:00:00" : 20.98003
   
    }
}
```

Comment: and what mongo query are you using? can you add it in youre code

Comment: and what mongo query are you using? can you add it in your code. "I am not able to convert it" does not mean a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $set: { data: { $mergeObjects: "$data" } } }
])
```

I think it is a very poor design to use timestamp values as field names.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but this. is only for graph representation